# Emitting signal when bytes are received in serial port

Tags: c++, boost, serial-port, signals, slot

I am trying to connect a signal and a slot in C++ using the boost libraries. My code currently opens a file and reads data from it. However, I am trying to improve the code so that it can read and analyze data in real time using a serial port. What I would like to do is have the analyze functions called only once there is data available in the serial port.

How would I go about doing this? I have done it in Qt before, however I cannot use signals and slots in Qt because this code does not use their moc tool.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you are actually struggling with? Detecting that you've received something on the serial port, or how to use `boost::signal`, or something else?

Comment: I am struggling with how to code it. Like how to use boost::signal with the serial port, such that when bytes are received on the serial port, a function is called. I want it to be like the Qt signal and slots without using Qt.

Answer (score 0):

Your OS (Linux) provides you with the following mechanism when dealing with the serial port.

You can set your serial port to noncanonical mode (by unsetting `ICANON` flag in `termios` structure). Then, if `MIN` and `TIME` parameters in `c_cc[]` are zero, the `read()` function will return if and only if there is new data in the serial port input buffer (see `termios` man page for details). So, you may run a separate thread responsible for getting the incoming serial data:

```
ssize_t count, bytesReceived = 0;
char myBuffer[1024];
while(1)
{
    if (count = read(portFD, 
        myBuffer + bytesReceived, 
        sizeof(myBuffer)-bytesReceived) > 0)
    {
     /*
       Here we check the arrived bytes. If they can be processed as a complete message,
       you can alert other thread in a way you choose, put them to some kind of 
       queue etc. The details depend greatly on communication protocol being used.
       If there is not enough bytes to process, you just store them in buffer
      */
         bytesReceived += count;
         if (MyProtocolMessageComplete(myBuffer, bytesReceived))
         {
              ProcessMyData(myBuffer, bytesReceived);
              AlertOtherThread(); //emit your 'signal' here
              bytesReceived = 0;  //going to wait for next message
         }
    }
    else
    {
     //process read() error
    }
}
```

The main idea here is that the thread calling `read()` is going to be active only when new data arrives. The rest of the time OS will keep this thread in wait state. Thus it will not consume CPU time. It is up to you how to implement the actual `signal` part.

The example above uses regular `read` system call to get data from port, but you can use the `boost` class in the same manner. Just use syncronous read function and the result will be the same.

Comment: Thank you very much. How do I unset the ICANON flag and set the MIN and TIME parameters in c_cc[]?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. So I am currently running your code, but none of the bytes are actually being printed. I opened the port, which works fine, and have set all the settings the way you instructed to. However, it won't read the data.

Comment: There are lots of things to consider when dealing with serial ports. You must set the same baud rate, data bits and parity on both ports. The flow control is better to be left disabled, at least for initial tests. All these settings are done in 'termios'  structure. For embedded systems there may be need to set the serial port mode (RS232, RS485, RS422). Such ports will also have non-standard pin layout. If everything is set correctly on both ports you are using, and there is still no data, make sure that the sending application is really sending data and that the cable is correct